# Potential leak of an object stored into 'cfuuid'

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

When I analyzed my project, I found this problem that I can't resolve. The code is like this:

```
NSString *udidString;
udidString = [[self class] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
if(!udidString)
{
    CFUUIDRef cfuuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    udidString = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, cfuuid));
    [[self class] setObject:udidString forKey:@"deviceID"];
}
```

How do I release the "cfuuid"?

Comment: why don't you use the NSUUID class? `uuidString = [[[NSUUID alloc] init] UUIDString];`

Answer (score 1):

For every object that you create with a CF*Create function, you should release it with [CFRelease](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRelease). This is part of the [Core Foundation ownership policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).